# Why is pip trying to install ctypes?

Tags: python, pip, distutils

I've tried creating a simple little package and uploaded it to PyPi.  When I try to install it however, pip tries to download and install ctypes (and fails at compiling it..):

```
(dev) C:\work\dev>pip install --upgrade dosbox-screen
Downloading/unpacking dosbox-screen
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dosbox-screen
Downloading/unpacking ctypes (from dosbox-screen)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ctypes
    warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
    warning: no files found matching 'NEWS.txt'
    warning: no files found matching 'ctypes\.CTYPES_DEVEL'
Downloading/unpacking colorama (from dosbox-screen)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package colorama
Installing collected packages: dosbox-screen, ctypes, colorama
  Running setup.py install for dosbox-screen
  Running setup.py install for ctypes
    building '_ctypes' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command C:\work\dev\Scripts\python.exe -..
```

I'm using Python 2.6.6 in a virtual env, so any ctypes requirement should already be satisfied:

```
(dev) C:\work\dev>python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.__file__
'c:\\python26\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.pyc'
```

The first version of my setup.py file listed it as a requirement, but the current version does not:

```
setup(
    name='dosbox-screen',
    version='0.0.3',
    requires=['colorama'],
    install_requires=['colorama'],
    ...
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you upload the new version?  It looks like pip is installing the older version (with the ctypes dep) that you mention.  Try passing -v arguments to get more verbose output.

Comment: Thanks. The -v argument showed me that pip was trying to build the ctypes it had downloaded previously (but never successfully built).  Once I deleted the build folder (containing a file called `pip-delete-this-directory.txt` :-)  everything went smoothly.